# Reading text from file into string dynamically and remove odd character in c

Tags: c, file

When I'm reading the string I want to replace every char which is not a-z or A-Z or 0-9 by ' ' but I also not to put two spaces in a row.

I created the following code to read a text from file and clean it a bit like I described:

```
char *getText (FILE *file) {
    bool lastWasLegal = true;
    char *text, *q;
    int textLength = 0;
    char token;
    int i = 0;
    text = malloc(sizeof(char));
    while ((token = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (isLegalChar(token))
        {
            lastWasLegal = true;
            text[i] = token;
            i++;
            q = realloc(text, (strlen(text) + 2) * sizeof(char));
            if (!q) {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            text = q;
        }
        else {
            if (lastWasLegal)
            {
                text[i] = ' ';
                i++;
                q = realloc(text, (strlen(text) + 2) * sizeof(char));
                if (!q) {
                    printf("Out of memory\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                text = q;
                lastWasLegal = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

The `isLegalChar` function is:

```
bool isLegalChar (char a) {
    if (a <= 90 && a >= 65) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (a <= 122 && a >= 97) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (isdigit(a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it's got a problem I can't find - when my file is:

> hello, world
>   bye

The output is:

> hello world bye?

but the expected output is:

> hello world bye

(which means without the question mark).

But if the file is just:

> hello world

The output is ok:

> hello world

To be specific I'm trying to replace all the characters which are not digits or numbers and replace them with `' '` but without having double spaces.

I think it's a memory problem but I still can't find it.

Comment: I know the name of the post isn't matching the question i asked but I wasn't sure how to name it

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: The input text without chars which are not digits or letters and with not double ' '. I'll edit thanks

Comment: You might want to mention the expected output *explicitly* in your question. From what you described, it seems that your code appends an unexpected question mark `?` (I have no idea why), but maybe it's not the only problem. If you mentioned something like "expected output is X, real output is Y", it would be much easier to see the difference. Also, for the case of correct output, please mention the output *explicitly*, and don't just say "The output is ok". This will make your question clearer.

Comment: ok I'll edit now, but can you try to tell whats the problem? @anatolyg

Comment: oh I totally forgot it thanks I'll check if it was the problem

Comment: It's working! Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: `getc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `EOF` is an `int` value, so by stuffing the return value of `getc()` into a `char` you can't reliably detect `EOF`.

Comment: Note that C does not require that character encoding be ASCII. Much better, and portable, to use `isalnum()` instead of your `isLegalChar()` function (which is already using `isdigit()`).

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling I wasn't familiar  with     isalnum().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the look of it you're not appending a '\0' when you are finished composing the string, so that whatever is using the return value of getText doesn't know where the string ends and may (or may not) print garbage at the end of the string.